# How to read a text file and parse it to JSON format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, text

I have a text file with the following format.

```
Order|AA|BB|CC|DD
2|status1|Cdd.int|true|false
12|status2|Cdd.String|true|false
1|status3|Cdd.Float|false|true
```

1. I would like to read this text file
2. I would like to append also metadata with an empty value
3. I am only interested in `Order, AA, BB, and CC` with sort by order
   and then parse it into JSON format as follows.

The expected output looks like the following.

```
{
 "fields": [
 {
    "metadata": {},
    "name" : "status3",
    "type" : "Float",
    "nullable" : false
},
{
    "metadata": {},
    "name" : "status1",
    "type" : "int",
    "nullable" : true
},
{
    "metadata": {},
    "name" : "status2",
    "type" : "String",
    "nullable" : true
}
],
'type':'struct'
}
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You have basically three questions: 1) read that CSV (ok, PSV), 2) add extra data, 3) write to JSON. Separate out the steps.

Comment: Yes. That is true indeed and not CSV but text file.

Comment: Your file is a pipe separated file, which is commonly referred to as a variant of CSV (but using a `|` instead if `,` as a separator). CSV is a text format.

Comment: Okay. Any possible solution to achieve that?

Comment: Reading CSV (also with other separators) is built-in: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html, but my point was more that you are essentially asking three questions. You should solve each step separately, and if necessary asking about the individual steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we have the data stored in a txt file `file.txt` as follows:

```
Order|AA|BB|CC|DD
2|status1|Cdd.int|true|false
12|status2|Cdd.String|true|false
1|status3|Cdd.Float|false|true
```

The following code does what you need (explained in the comments of the code itself):

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

#read csv
df = pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep = "|")

headers = {"AA": "name", 
           "BB": "type",
           "CC": "nullable"
}

#Drop columns which are not in headers dict
df.drop([c for c in df.columns if c not in headers.keys()], inplace=True, axis=1)

#Rename columns based on headers dict
df.rename(columns = headers, inplace = True)

#Format columns
df["type"] = df["type"].str.split(".").str[1].str.lower()

#Build your final dict
output = {"fields": [], "type": "struct"}
for n, row in df.iterrows():
    data_dict = {"metadata": {}}
    data_dict.update(row.to_dict())
    output["fields"].append(data_dict)

#Save json
with open("output.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(output, f, indent = 4)
```

The output json (`output.json`) is as follows:

```json
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "metadata": {},
            "name": "status1",
            "type": "int",
            "nullable": true
        },
        {
            "metadata": {},
            "name": "status2",
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
        },
        {
            "metadata": {},
            "name": "status3",
            "type": "float",
            "nullable": false
        }
    ],
    "type": "struct"
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without the 3rd party dependency `pandas`. And I also would say the code looks easier to read and less complex.

The ordering is done with a step in between. Each CSV line/row is stored as `dict` element which itself is in a parent `dict` and indexed by the (cast to `int`) value of `Order`. Then this `dict` is sorted by it's keys (which are `Order`) and then transformed to a `list`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import io
import csv
import json

# simulate a csv-file
csv_string = '''Order|AA|BB|CC|DD
2|status1|Cdd.int|true|false
12|status2|Cdd.String|true|false
1|status3|Cdd.Float|false|true
'''
csv_string = csv_string.split('\n')

result = {
    'fields': [],
    'type': 'struct'
}

# store the result temporary
temp_result = {}

reader = csv.reader(csv_string, delimiter='|')
next(reader)  # ignore the header
for row in reader:
    # ignore empty rows
    if not row:
        continue

    # use 'Order' as key
    temp_result[int(row[0])] = {
        'metadata': {},
        'name': row[1],
        'type': row[2][4:],
        'nullable': row[3] == 'true'
    }

# sort the temporary result by their keys
temp_result = {key: temp_result[key] for key in sorted(temp_result)}
# transform to a list
temp_result = list(temp_result.values())

# final result
result = {
    'fields': temp_result,
    'type': 'struct'
}

# show result
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

In your real or productive code you have to replace `csv_string` with a file-like object.

```
csv_file_path = pathlib.Path('data.csv')
with csv_file_path.open('r') as file_handle:
    reader = csv.reader(file_handle, delimiter='|')
```

#### Advice about result

Your resulting data structure looks a bit wired and unpythonic. I would suggest to remove the `name` element from the `dicts` but use it as a dict key.

```
{
    "fields": {
        "status1": {
            "metadata": {},
            "type": "int",
            "nullable": true
        },
        "status2": {
            "metadata": {},
            "type": "String",
            "nullable": true
        },
        "status3": {
            "metadata": {},
            "type": "Float",
            "nullable": false
        }
    },
    "type": "struct"
}
```